# Fortran performance of array of derived type of arrays

Tags: fortran, derived-types

I want to create an allocatable array `Arr` of derived types `Dir` that contain an allocatable array `R`.
Initialization goes something like this:

```
TYPE( Dir ), ALLOCATABLE :: Arr( : )
ALLOCATE( Arr( na ) )
DO i = 1, na
  ALLOCATE( Arr( i ) % R( nr ) )
END DO
```

I'm slightly worried that the data of a single `Dir` of `Arr` won't all be in the same location in memory, since I imagine one section of memory will be used when allocating `Arr`, and then another will be used when allocating `R`. I'm guessing it would be faster to have the data of a `Dir` in one location since my code will do a lot of work with the data of each `Dir` at a time. However I don't know too much about this.

Right now, instead of using derived type `Dir`, my code uses a separate array for each of the components that `Dir` would have. I’m considering bundling them them up into one array of `Dir` to make my code more elegant/logical, and I’m wondering how this will affect performance.

My questions are:

Should I expect performance to depend much on whether the data of a `Dir` is in one location?

If so, is there a way to initialize `Arr` so that the data of a `Dir` is in one location?

Do you think having the data of `Arr` in separate arrays could have different performance than having it in one array of `Dir`?

Comment: Have you done any benchmarking?  If the number of elements in `ARR(:)` is small and the number of elements in `R` is small, everything will like fit a memory cache.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it unless you know there is a issue. https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/#:~:text=Premature%20optimization%20is%20spending%20a,is%20credited%20to%20Donald%20Knuth.